# Increase in curvature over a short distance

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $p, q \in \Sigma$ such that $d_{\mathbb{R}^3}(p,q) < \epsilon$. Suppose that $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small so that the ball $B$ centered at $p$ for radius $\epsilon$ intersects $\Sigma$ in a single connected component, a $2$-ball. Thus the distance between $p$ and $q$ on the manifold $d_{\Sigma}(p,q) \leq d_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}(p,q) < \epsilon$. Let $\kappa$ be the maximum principal curvature at $p$ in absolute value. The maximum principal curvature varies smoothly as we walk along $\Sigma$ from $p$ to $q$ within $B$. How much larger can the maximum principal curvature at $q$ be, than at $p$, as a function of $\epsilon$?

Comment: As stated, there is no relation.

Comment: There has to be. If starting at $p$ I walk along $\Sigma$ toward $q$, the curvature at each point must vary smoothly. If I only walk for a short distance then the curvature can't have varied that much.

Comment: Just because the Euclidean distance between p and q is small, that doesn't mean you can get to q from p by walking a short distance along $\Sigma$.

Comment: Yes it does. It just needs to be sufficiently small so that the ball $B$ centered at $p$ with radius $\epsilon$, intersects $\Sigma$ in a single connected component (I.e. $B\cap \Sigma$ is a 2-ball).

Comment: Regarding the distances something like this holds: there exists $\varepsilon_0>0$ s.t. for every $\varepsilon<\varepsilon_0$ it holds that if $d^{\mathbb{R}^3}(p,q)<\varepsilon$, then $d^{\Sigma}(p,q)<C(\varepsilon) d^{\mathbb{R}^3}(p,q)$ and $C(\varepsilon)\to1$ for $\varepsilon \to 0$. (At least if $\Sigma$ is compact.)

Comment: Yep, that's certainly true.

Comment: If that's what you meant, then your original question is missing a lot of quantifiers. Please edit your question to reflect the question you actually want to ask.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Just use a surface that is flat at $p$ and has a fold at $q$ (imagine a piece of paper folded in half). You can make the maximum principal curvature at $q$ as large as you want, while leaving the curvatures at $p$ unchanges.

Comment: I've already thought of that. That's the point of wanting an expression as a function of $\epsilon$. The curvature can't got from 0 to $K$ discontinuously, it must do so smoothly. So I want to know, if I don't travel too far away from $p$, how much can the curvature increase.

Comment: Your question is still misstated: comparing the curvature at two fixed points is meaningless. It may be more meaningful to ask whether the appropriate derivatives of the principal curvatures are related to the curvatures themselves, but even that is doubtful: in the case of curves, curvature and torsion are not related.

Comment: I don't understand. In the example I give, the curvature can be made smooth.

Comment: Inequality in OP is right ?